# Retrieve system commands without reading sources

Tags: command-line, command, strace

Sometimes I wonder how Linux programs achieve certain results knowing that they internally use system calls (`system()` or `exec()` in C programs). Given a working binary I wonder if it is possible to know easily which commands where executed. In a concrete example I use the genealogy tool `gramps` to build a family tree. I assume that it generates certain graphs using `graphviz` (using command line tools rather than libraries). Now I want to reproduce the same manually on the command line. This task would be simplified a lot if I knew the commands used by `gramps`. I could download and look at the sources to find out, but I wonder if I can obtain this information more easily using debugging tools such as `strace`, something like `strace gramps 2>/dev/stdout | grep system`. Note that I would not like to search the binary using a hex editor unless this can be automated. Looking at the sources directly should be easier in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strace -o dumpfile.strace -f -e trace=process $your $app $with $parameters
```

You find the result in the file `dumpfile.strace`.

Comment: I tried this. It looks promising, however I find e.g. `execve("/usr/bin/dot", ["dot", "-Tpdf", "-o/home/user/temp/r"..., "/tmp/tmp7ebycv.gv"], [/* 91 vars */]) = 0`. Obviously the command is abbreviated in the output. It would be important to know the complete command. Is there an option?

Comment: @highsciguy `strace -v -s 128 ...`